# Revoking company iOS distribution certificates and creating a new one with a new key

Tags: ios, certificate, signing, apple-developer

I've searched the web far and wide but haven't found this particular use case or corresponding answer.

Let me explain the situation:

We're an app development team in a company which has recently been taken over. The takeover company had an existing Apple developer account but outsourced iOS app development to an agency.

Since our job is to create apps for public release, we too need to option to sign our apps for distribution.

The problem is, there are 3 active distribution certificates (which is the limit for organisation accounts) and they are all signed with a private key the agency generated.

My suggestion would be to revoke one of the (oldest) distribution certificates and generate a new one with a private key that our team generated.

My question is, what impact will this have? I've found that revoking a distribution certificate has no impact on the apps that are signed with it and that you just can generate a new one if you want to update the app, but that all assumes the new distribution certificate is signed with the same private key. What happens when you have 2 active distribution certificates signed with a different private key? What are the best practices for this?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have 2 distribution certificates signed with the same private key, you're done:  just delete one and use the other to update the other apps.  (If all 3 are, then delete 2).
2. If all three distribution certificates have different private keys, and if you insist on a new one, make a list of apps signed with each key and prioritize.  Then delete the certificate with least cost knowing that you can't update those apps.
3. Alternatively, give up your wish for a new certificate and just use one of theirs.

Comment: I can't use their distribution certificates because we don't have the private key, and the agency doesn't want to hand it over.

Comment: But what you're saying is that I can't update app Foo signed with certificate A if I revoke certificate A and replace it with certificate B with a different private key? These apps will forever be locked then?

Comment: Then in effect, you can't update their apps.  Why not delete all their keys?  All their products in the store and purchased will be fine.

Comment: No, I misread *you* saying that.  I just updated an old app with a different certificate/private key so I was a little surprised.